# How to run two opengl render and rendering to one screen

Tags: opengl

We have the AVM(around view monitor) which is developed by QT that we need to porting to a new platform which no QT support.

This AVM will create two QT windows(part of the whole screen) that each window will run OpenGL to render the output to parts of the screen.(Eg. 50%s for each window):

[image: QT dual windows]

Without QT support how we can implement it using OpengGL(EGL) directly:

1. Create multiple window(or surface) for each OpenGL?
2. Each OpenGL render only render part(50%)  of the screen?

Environment information:

1.Embedded Linux
2. OpenGL(egl), weston.

Comment: What do you mean by AVM?

Comment: What operating system / graphics environment are you developing for? Windows, *BSD, Linux/X11, Linux/Wayland, something else? As for rendering multiple views: You can use multiple windows, using a single OpenGL context. Or you can use a single window spanning all the screens and use glViewport+glScissor to render into multiple regions of that windows.

Comment: update the question.

Comment: The second approach will save you from context switching and will allow you to share GPU memory stored data between both "windows"

Comment: Fix the issuse by removing   //  glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); before the second opengl render

Answer (score 0):

remove the code 
 glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
in QT with two window, each window will call glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT) before rendering,  should remove this when no QT support.